# Creating script block is underfined

Tags: javascript

I run a script which gets variables e.g. screen size.

I want to make those variables available for later scripts to build content based on what they might be.

So, I run the script at the top of the page and at the end the script I create a new script section and spit out the variables.

The problem is that there is an undefined tag before the first variable and I have no idea why?

This is the code:

```
// Create the element
var script = document.createElement("script");

script.innerHTML = '';

// build content
//variable_list += "var screen_width="+sw+";\n";
//variable_list += "var screen_height="+sh+";";

// Add script content
script.innerHTML = variable_list;
// Append
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

It looks like this in the DOM which of course causes an error:

```
<script>
  undefinedvar screen_width=357;
  var screen_height=505;
</script>
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What is `variable_list`?

Answer (score 4):

I suspect because you haven't initialized `variable_list` to the empty string before you start appending to it. The statement

```
variable_list += ...
```

is equivalent to

```
variable_list = variable_list + ...
```

If you haven't initialized `variable_list` prior to running that statement, then it will have the value `undefined`, which, when concatenated with another string, will be stringified itself into `"undefined"`, and concatenated into the result string.

To solve this problem, add the following statement prior to the first concatenation:

```
variable_list = '';
```

Comment: Doh! Exactly right you are, I'd fixed before I saw this - thanks, will accept when i can